# How can emacs detect when a file has been modified by another program?

Tags: warning

Does emacs have a way of detecting when a file it is editing has been changed by another program?

Can it warn and generate a message when that happens, rather than warn you when you are about to edit or save it?

Comment: There are a lot of similar Questions. This for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031051/emacs-notify-when-a-file-has-been-modified-externally

Comment: I have already checked the question you mentioned, but after further search it turns out that `emacs` now has gained `inotify` support since that question was asked - [`file-notify-add-watch`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Notifications.html)